# QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN not works over raspberry pi crosscompile

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, qdebug

I adjust the QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN on build environment both for pc and raspberry.

When I did a run on pc, debug gives me an output as I adjusted but when a did a run on raspberry pi (deployment) , debug gives me an output like I didn't adjust....

here is adjustment;

```
QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN = "[(%{file}:%{line}) - %{message}"
```

Comment: how are you setting that???

Answer (score 1):

in order to work you need to do:

1. `qSetMessagePattern(QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN);`
2. `qInstallMessageHandler(yourCustomMessageHandle`r);

Comment: to where I need to add these ?

Comment: Excuse me for a late reply but when I tried your suggest, compiler gives me an error with qInstallMessageHandler for no matching function....

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the message pattern; at the beginning of `int main()` add `qputenv("QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN", QByteArray("[(%{file}:%{line}) - %{message}"));`

Try this snippet:

```
#include <QDebug>

#include <unistd.h>

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/ [])
{
    qputenv("QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN", QByteArray("[(%{file}:%{line}) - %{message}"));

    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        qDebug() << "Message";
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me for a late reply but I have tried your suggest. It works on pc side, but If I deploy to raspberry pi, I couldnt see what I have expected ....

Comment: Please note that I'm trying to deploy the project to raspberry pi from pc and I wantted to see this pattern on pc while program running on raspberry (deployed)...

Comment: I work daily on embedded systems, and this is the way to go! Are you deploying the application via QtCreator?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with QtCreator.... but I want to add sth, I have created the os with buildroot... Can be sth missing on OS ?

Comment: I suggest trying this small snippet on the desktop. If it doesn't work you have to check some project/QtCreator option. If it works then move on the embedded system; I suggest cross-compile/deploy via QtCreator, then run the app from the debug serial o by connecting via SSH.